# jface.resource.ImageDescriptor - How to tell which kind of file properties will be properly displayed?

Tags: java, image, swt, jface

I am desperate.

I have the following code in my application to load PNG files:

```
public static Image loadImageFromLocal(Class<?> clazz, String fileName) {
   ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(clazz, fileName);
   Image image = imageDesc.createImage();
   return image;
}
```

So far so good until I tried to download some files from the internet and load them using the same logic. The downloaded files are not properly displayed. When I apply my SWT program logic to show the original files, it works fine.

I tried to find out what is the difference between the files - those correctly displayed are of 8 bits and those downloaded, nowadays, of course is 32-bit color depth.

I had then changed the color depth of those downloaded from 32-bit to 8-bit. Nothing happens, my program still not able to correctly display them.

I also tried to change the format of the downloaded files to JPG, it still won't work.

Which direction should I go to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is the Eclipse internal problem. Everything works fine after I delete and import the project in Eclipse again.